# How to append an entity to a datastore in Go Lang

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

Need info on how to append an entity in Google cloud data store.

Put function is always overwritten with new values.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

09-OCT-2017:

**I Used below code, but still updating entity instead of appending.(its erasing old & updated with new value, but i want to retain both values)**

```
client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
tx, err := client.NewTransaction(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
}

fmt.Fprint(w, input)
taskKey := datastore.NameKey("Entity", "stringID", nil)
var task Entity
if err := tx.Get(taskKey, &task); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("tx.Get: %v", err)
}
task.Value = input
if _, err := tx.Put(taskKey, &task); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("tx.Put: %v", err)
}
if _, err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("tx.Commit: %v", err)
}
```

Comment: What is `Entity` and `input`? Please post them and what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: Entity is struct & input is string.
_type Entity struct {
 Value string
}

input := r.URL.Query().Get("input")_

Comment: And what do you want to "append"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: First Run -> input -> i will drive value "abc", after that in second run, i ll drive "efg" and so on... i want to store all these in same entity. currently "efg" is overwriting on "abc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be only one instance, only one entity bound / denoted by the same datastore key.

And entities (bound to a key) can only be overwritten, not updated / extended / appended gradually.

So if you already have an entity saved, to update/  modify it, you have to first load it, then modify the entity in memory, and write out (save) the modified entity. This save will overwrite the existing entity in the datastore.

If for a property you want to store multiple values, the type of that property must support storing multiple values. [Slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) in Go are such types.

So in your example your entity should look like this:

```
type Entity struct {
    Values []string 
}
```

When you load an existing `Entity`, you have to append the new value to its `Values` field, something like this (in pseudo code):

```
e := ... // load existing entity
e.Values = append(e.Values, input) // Append new data to Values
// And now save Entity (e) with the same key
```

In code:

```
client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
tx, err := client.NewTransaction(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
}

fmt.Fprint(w, input)
taskKey := datastore.NameKey("Entity", "stringID", nil)
var task Entity
if err := tx.Get(taskKey, &task); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("tx.Get: %v", err)
}
task.Values = append(task.Values, input)
if _, err := tx.Put(taskKey, &task); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("tx.Put: %v", err)
}
if _, err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("tx.Commit: %v", err)
}
```

If you need to index by this `Values` property, you might run into troubles if it contains many values. See this possible duplicate for more details: [App Engine Datastore: How to set multiple values on a property using golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859001/app-engine-datastore-how-to-set-multiple-values-on-a-property-using-golang/29870246#29870246)

If you run into this problem, you should consider modeling and storing your data in a different format, e.g. saving in multiple entities, where one entity would only store a single `input`, connected with the key it belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Double thumbs up. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should:

- get an entity first,
- then change a value
- and after that update the entity in the datastore.

Please consult with docs: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#updating_an_entity:

> To update an existing entity, modify the properties of the entity
>   previously retrieved and store it using the key:
>
> ```
> tx, err := client.NewTransaction(ctx)
> if err != nil {
>         log.Fatalf("client.NewTransaction: %v", err)
> }
> var task Task
> if err := tx.Get(taskKey, &task); err != nil {
>         log.Fatalf("tx.Get: %v", err)
> }
> task.Priority = 5
> if _, err := tx.Put(taskKey, task); err != nil {
>         log.Fatalf("tx.Put: %v", err)
> }
> if _, err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
>         log.Fatalf("tx.Commit: %v", err)
> }
> ```

Comment: I used below code. I just curious why below code doesnt work(append).k := datastore.NameKey("Entity", "stringID", nil)
 
 e := Entity{input}
 if _, err = client.Put(ctx, k, &e); err != nil {

 }

Comment: I updated query as per your suggestion, but still no success.